# How to exit Toddler Lock without touchscreen

Tags: locked-out

My touch screen broke while Toddler Lock was enabled. Is there a way to disable it without touching the four corners?

My device is rooted and developer options are enabled. So I can access it via "adb".

Answer (score 0):

Simulate input events for touch screen via adb:

```
FOUR CORNERS:
adb shell input tap 10 100
adb shell input tap 510 100
adb shell input tap 510 950
adb shell input tap 10 950

OKAY:
adb shell input tap 350 900
```

Edit: Note: The coordinates of the taps depend on the screen size resolution. These coordinates work on a device with a resolution of 960 x 540 pixels.

Comment: Weren't those taps relative to the screen size of your device?